# PKDrawing different results for Dark Mode and Light Mode

Tags: ios, ios13

When using `PKDrawing` in dark mode the image generated by [imageFromRect:scale:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/pkdrawing/3237277-imagefromrect) returns pen drawings in white color. In light mode it uses black color. The background is usually transparent.

Question: How can PKDrawing be forced to always behave like in light mode?

Comment: See https://onepile.app/download-ios for an example

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it like this, by using traitCollection.performAsCurrent:

```
let darkImage = thumbnail(drawing: drawing, thumbnailRect: frameForImage, traitCollection: UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .dark))

func thumbnail(drawing: PKDrawing, thumbnailRect: CGRect, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIImage {

    var image = UIImage()
    traitCollection.performAsCurrent {
        image = drawing.image(from: thumbnailRect, scale: 2.0)
    }
    return image
}
```

Comment: This is super awesome! It works perfectly. Thanks Stefan, saved my day.

Comment: That works perfectly for ios - but any idea how to do same on OSX ?